# Flutter - ReorderableListView.builder - Change style of selected element for drag/drop

Tags: flutter

I would like to give user some feedback that he select some element in ReorderableListView.builder and now he can drag and drop it (change borde color or something like that).

Is there any way?

Thank you and BR!

M.